# Questions about yii

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I install yii frame work and run one project in -> c:xampp/htdocs/yiitest

I The creation of one change in c:xampp/htdocs/yiitest/protected/views/site/index.php

But I did not see any change in Browser

pleas help me for this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into `localhost/yiitest/site/index` url for seeing changes. This url maps to `actionIndex` in `SiteController` and actionIndex renders `site/index.php` file.